# Is there a way to force AutoCompleteTextView's context list to show above the view?

Tags: android

I have a custom AutoCompleteTextView. When I have more than one results in the list then the context list shows above the AutoCompleteTextView but when it narrows down the answer to 1 the context list is moved so its below the AutoCompleteTextView which is my case puts it below the softkeyboard so you can see its result.

Here is an example with 2 items in the list. 
[image: an example with 2 items in the list]

and here the result has moved below:
[image: and here the result has moved below]

I know the list is there so its not because there is no result. 
So is there a way to force the list to show above the AutoCompleteTextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out a way to do it.

For some some people it might work with adding:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

to you activity's tag in the manifest. But this didn't work for me. Nor did some other changes to the xml of the layout where I have the AutoCompleteTextView.

So what works for me is by using setDropdownHeight & setDropdownVerticalOffset in the AutoCompleteTextview's TextWatcher.

I did the following:

```
helper.spinnerCreator = new SpinnerAdapter(context, R.layout.row_spinner, newusers); 
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(helper.spinnerCreator);
height = getCorrectOffset(newusers.size());
autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHeight(height);
autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownVerticalOffset(-(height + offset));
```

And to get the height I made something like this:

```
private int getCorrectOffset(int items) {
    float height = rowHeight * (float) items;
    if (items > 2) height = rowHeight * 2.7f;
    int s = (int) height;
    return s;
}
```

The offset is the height of the autocomplete textview. And rowHeight is the height in pixels of each row in the context list.